# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть предложение такого плана: "Единственное, чего ему не удалось понять, (это то, что...) знает ли его враг, что..." Можно ли опускать "это то, что" или это уже будет нелитературно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно без "что": "Единственное, чего ему не удалось понять, это то, знает ли его враг, что..." 
Можно, особенно в разговорное речи, и "это то" опустить, грамматика не нарушится.

К сожалению, даже в этих случаях фраза стилистически неудачна (тяжеловесна), по возможности и от второго "что" следует избавиться.